# Runnig install.sh file with python

Tags: python, linux, bash

How can i run install.sh file using python code.Purpose is to implement software update functionality.The sh file is generated using makeself and it is a self-extractable archive.I get this output when i use `os.system` or `subprocess.run`

> ## Failed to parse arguments: Unknown option -title

NB: The Script file don't require any arguments

Comment: Hey, is this helpful https://askubuntu.com/q/38661

Comment: Search for `os.system`.

Comment: `os.system('./install.sh')` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.call` (Python <=3.5) and `subprocess.run` (Python >3.5) would be a safer alternative to `os.system`.

Comment: tried this also not working

Comment: as i mentioned this is a self-extractable archive

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 : Use SubProcess

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['/path/to/your/script.sh', 'argument1', 'argument2', ..., 'argumentn'])
```

Solution 2 : Use Os

```py
import os
os.system('/path/to/your/script.sh argument1 argument2 ... argumentn'])
```

Both will work fine, if you have the choice it's better to use subprocess since it will handle for you the formatting of your command with thing such as space in the command line or special characters.

Comment: i tired this since it is a self-extractable archive , i don't know that will make difference or not